# Could not find support-v4.jar (com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0)

Tags: android, react-native

i am running sample application using [react-native-webrtc](https://github.com/thoqbk/rewebrtc) module. I am trying to run the application in android but i am getting an error like this...

```
 * What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':WebRTCModule'.
> Could not find support-v4.jar (com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0).
  Searched in the following locations:
      https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/23.4.0/support-v4-23.4.0.jar

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 5.673 secs
```

Please give me any suggestions...
here is the modules i am using in this application...

```
    "react": "~15.4.0",
    "react-native": "0.41.2",
    "react-native-webrtc": "^1.54.7",
    "socket.io-client": "^1.7.2"
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue is due to your local SDK version doesn't meet to the mentioned version (23.4.0),

To solve this issue, Go to android studio package manager and Install 23.4.0 SDK Version in it, else Update Android studio, and use latest SDK version which is 27.

Comment: hi @Nandam Mahesh, thank you for your reply..... I updated the SDK version, but error is not fixed.....

Comment: Hey harika, its okay, may i know your react and react-native version along with sdk version which you are using now ?